# Why QPainter might reject to work inside paintEvent?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, paintevent

I have:

```
class QTextEditEnter : public QTextEdit
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    QTextEditEnter( QWidget *_parent ) : QTextEdit(_parent)
    {
        this -> setFrameStyle( QFrame::Sunken ); // Sunken!
    }

protected:
    virtual void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent * event);
    virtual void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *_event)
    {
        QTextEdit::paintEvent( _event );
        QPainter pnt(this);
        pnt.setPen( QColor( 0, 0, 0, 0xff ));
        pnt.drawRect( 0, 0, width(), height());
    }

    signals:
        void signalPressEnter();
};
```

that gives:

```
QPainter::begin: Widget painting can only begin as a result of a paintEvent
QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
QPainter::drawRects: Painter not active
QPainter::begin: Widget painting can only begin as a result of a paintEvent
QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
QPainter::drawRects: Painter not active
```

Why that could be?

**Update**

```
// QPainter( this )
// QTextEdit::paintEvent at the begining of custom PaintEvent
// RESULT: "QPainter::begin: Widget painting can only begin as a result of a paintEvent" ...
virtual void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *_event)
{
    QTextEdit::paintEvent( _event );
    QPainter pnt( this );
    pnt.setPen( QColor( 0, 0, 0, 0xff ));
    pnt.drawRect( 0, 0, width()-1, height()-1);
}

// QPainter ( viewport() )
// QTextEdit::paintEvent at the begining of custom PaintEvent
// RESULT: works.
virtual void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *_event)
{
    QTextEdit::paintEvent( _event );
    QPainter pnt( viewport() );
    pnt.setPen( QColor( 0, 0, 0, 0xff ));
    pnt.drawRect( 0, 0, width()-1, height()-1);
}

// *** BONUS ***
// QPainter( viewport() ) or QPainter ( this )
// QTextEdit::paintEvent after QPainter() constructor.
// RESULT: Segmentation fault.
virtual void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *_event)
{
    QPainter pnt( viewport() );
    pnt.setPen( QColor( 0, 0, 0, 0xff ));
    QTextEdit::paintEvent( _event ); // WRONG PLACE!!!
    pnt.drawRect( 0, 0, width()-1, height()-1);
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are calling `QTextEditEnter::paintEvent()` explicitly somewhere. Could this be the case? It should only be called directly by Qt from the event loop.

Comment: Tilman Vogel i think no - didn't found any direct calling of it.

Comment: You can trace your program in debug mode, and check whether it outputs such messages. Provide us more info, plz.

Comment: @troyane o... i am not friendly with debugging such code, especially in linux which takes place in my case :)

Comment: In few words.
You must change build type (from release) to debug, then add a breakpoint to your code, and run (F5). Use debug controls (step into, step over) to trace your code in realtime. 

Have a luck!

Comment: @troyane i investigate this problem in linux, Visual Studio is not my option for now :)

Comment: its offtop, but I'm talking even about Linux, about QtCreator as IDE

Comment: Does this problem arise because of your paint code, or in the QTextEdit::paintEvent( _event ) call?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of

```
QPainter pnt(this);
```

try

```
QPainter pnt(viewport());
pnt.setPen(QColor( 0, 0, 0, 0xff ));
pnt.drawRect(viewport()->rect());
```

viewport() is the paintable area and could be whats causing the issue

Comment: Thank you! This helped! The viewport() is a method of QAbstractScrollArea (as i remember), but doesn't exist in ordinary QWidget. And in case you inherit QTextEdit you must remember to use "viewport()", but not "this". It is odd, because you have to remember it...